# App shut down when open the 4th time

Tags: android

I have a simple android app with just one activity. The app has an abstract class that extends surfaceview and implements Runnable. The app runs without problems when it is open for the first 3 times. However, the app shut down when it is opened at the 4th time. Then it can be opened again for the next 3 times and shut down at the 4th time and so on...Does anyone has an idea what is likely to be the cause?

```
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:359)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:385)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.example.meerkatrevolutionengine.Engine.onCreate(Engine.java:114)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-09 21:56:00.708: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: probably you have a static variable or something that android still keep it on for VM even you destroy your activity. Try to clean everything properly onDestroy method !

Comment: Your app ran out of memory - read the Stacktrace

Comment: Why are you spawining your own processes using Runnable - use AsyncTasks or IntentServices - sounds like your processes are still running in the background.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir Does it mean the onDestroy method needs to be overridden? what is the code like to clean everything properly? I set all the variables to null before initializing...but somehow it does not work

Comment: there is not enough detailed data to know what to clean, maybe you can share your code a bit, so we can understand whats going on

Comment: @SercanOzdemir code uploaded. Please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

the code is very dirty, first of all i must say it's so hard to read it.

Your problem is your activity implementing a runnable and even if you close your application that runnable never stops. So it accumlates on VM, thats why after a while you are getting crashed and VM getting restarted, that's why when you enter the 4rd time it comes OK.

Try to change your `p_running` variables to false onDestroy event. I mean override onDestroy like below:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
     p_running=false;
}
```

But that does not guarentee your code will work on 4rd times. Because VM does not understand your code should clean up immediatly. Thread won't stop a while. So you can try to stop Thread hardly but it's not a proper way.. So try to change your code another way..

Answer (score 0):

After using Bitmap object set it `=null` and use `System.GC` to free the memory
you can do that `onDestroy` of `Activity` or on `onDetachedFromWindow` of `View`